# How to get static variable's value in dll

Tags: c#, dll, static-members

I wanna build a DLL to store some data in a static dictionary variable(pdfDictionary) and provide a method **public static string GetItemValue(string sectionName, string itemName)** to get the specify value.When I add the DLL as a reference to Console Application,It works well.But in Windows Forms Application,I can't get value by using GetItemValue.Any help will be appreciated.

Define Dictionary:

```
    private static Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>> pdfDictionary = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>();
    //private static Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>> pdfDictionary ;
    public static Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>> PdfDictionary
    {
        get { return AdapterUtil.pdfDictionary; }
        set { AdapterUtil.pdfDictionary = value; }
    }
```

Write Dictionary:

```
        public static void WriteDictionary(string pdfFile)
    {
        string strResult = ExtractSpecifyAreaText(pdfFile, 0, 110, 907, 620);
        string strContent = RemoveWaterMark(strResult);
        Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>> pdfDict = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>();
        // some code


        AdapterUtil.pdfDictionary = pdfDict;
    }
```

Getting Item Value Method:

```
        public static string GetItemValue(string sectionName, string itemName)
    {

        switch (sectionName)
        {
            case "Section2":
                if (pdfDictionary.ContainsKey(sectionName))
                {
                    Dictionary<string, string> dic2 = pdfDictionary[sectionName];
                    if (dic2.ContainsKey(itemName))
                    {
                        return dic2[itemName];
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return @"No value";
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    return @"No value";
                }
            //other cases
            default:
                return @"No value";
        }
    }
```

Call Method in Console Application,I can get the phone number:

```
        string pdfFilePath = @"D:\test.pdf";
        PDFAdapter.AdapterUtil.WriteDictionary(pdfFilePath);
        //Get phone number
        string keyVal = PDFAdapter.AdapterUtil.GetItemValue(@"Section4", @"Phone Number");
        Console.WriteLine("Phone Number is {0}", keyVal);
        Console.ReadKey();
```

Call Method in Windows Forms Application,I get Nothing but no exception:

```
        private void btnBrowseSOF_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (this.ofdSOF.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) {
            string pdfFilePath = this.ofdSOF.FileName;
            this.txtSOF.Text = this.ofdSOF.FileName;
            PDFAdapter.AdapterUtil.WriteDictionary(pdfFilePath);
            //Get Nothing
            string keyVal = PDFAdapter.AdapterUtil.GetItemValue(@"Section4", @"Phone Number");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Check the file path which you sent to WriteDictionary method in console application and form application are equal.. Both should send "D:\test.pdf" to the WriteDictionary method.

Comment: I'm confused that I can get keyVal by using these code:PDFAdapter.AdapterUtil.GetItemValue(@"Section4", @"Phone Number") in Console Application,but It's not in Windows Form Application.Is it correct to get/set static variable?